# How can I do an overwrite with gong drag-drop?

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

I'm using gong solutions drag-drop to transfer items between two lists. I want to allow the dual behaviours of dragging an item to copy it to the dragged position, and dragging directly over an item to replace it.

So far I have managed to overlay an invisible itemscontrol for each item in the list which occupies half the height of the item. Then in the view model for each item I have a drop handler which adds a highlight adorner. Unfortunately the itemscontrol is appearing on top of the row (which it must to receive input), and is blocking the click of a button on that row.

Before I continue down this dark path, is there a non-hacky way of achieving what I want? Here is the relevant part of my view:

```
<ListView Name="Templates" dd:DragDrop.DropHandler="{Binding}" dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True" dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Grid x:Name="Grid">
                            <GridViewRowPresenter />
                            <Grid Name="DropHandler" Height="10" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <ItemsControl Name="TemplateOverwriteHack" dd:DragDrop.DropHandler="{Binding}" dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="False" dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True" Opacity="0.0" /
```

Thanks.